# Cakephp test is breaking at middle of function

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I'm creating a cakephp test (using phpunit) and somehow it stops at the middle of the function.

So i'm testing the StartController, where it calls the function createInstitution.

In the middle of it, I have the following code:

```
(...)
var_dump("0");
$newEntry = $this->InstitutionRegistration->findEntryByEmail($email);
var_dump("1");
(...)
```

When I run the test, it prints the "0", but after that, it no longer runs the test.

As this controller $fixtures variable, i have the following:

```
public $fixtures = [
    'app.users',
    'app.institution_registration',
    'app.institutions',
];
```

I use a function from UsersTable before the excert of the code that i've pasted

I get no errors on log, neither on the command line.

Thanks for your help. If more information needed, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded the problem.

Had to put a try-catch and print the exception error on that function to discover what the problem was.. It was a Mysql error that wasn't being listed.